# How to check with Google Test zero or one function call?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I want to write a test, that invokes 2 functions in different threads, and I expect that depending on which function will work first happpens this:

```
EXPECT_CALL(foo, bar(arg_1));
```

or this:

```
EXPECT_CALL(foo, bar(arg_1)).RetiresOnSaturation();
EXPECT_CALL(foo, bar(arg_2)).RetiresOnSaturation();
EXPECT_CALL(foo, bar(arg_1)).RetiresOnSaturation();
```

exactly in this order.
What is the easiest way to do it? I'm pretty new to Google Test.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What are `foo` and `bar`? What are `arg_1` and `arg_2`? What does `I expect that depending on which function will work first happpens this` mean?

Comment: @Srikanth The question is clear (and what `foo` and `bar` are) in context of [tag:googletest] and [tag:googlemock].

Comment: Ok, I will give them names if that will help to understand problem. I invoke methods ProcessRequest() and OnConnectionStatusChange(bool isConnected) of my object foo. Foo::ProcessRequest() must return answer via function bar(string msg) if we are connected. If we not connected it also returns answer (from cache) and than send message informig that data may be outdated. Foo::OnConnectionStatusChange(true) sends message about restoring connection for request that was asked before.

Comment: So what I fear is race between reconnection and request. Client shouldn't get messages in order like this: first he gets answer on request, then message about recnnection from OnConnectionStatusChange, and then message about disconnected state from ProcessRequest. If he will get only first, or if he will get three in right order, we're fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can't do either-or patterns or conditional expectations, just optional expectations, set the fixed expectation with arg1, and an optional (Times(AtMost(1))) expectation with arg2, put those in sequence, and have the optional expectation add the third expectation.

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
class Foo {
public:
  MOCK_METHOD1(bar, void(int));
};

class ExpectCall1
{
public:
  ExpectCall1(Foo& foo) : foo_(foo) {}
  void operator()()
  {
    EXPECT_CALL(foo_, bar(1)).Times(1);
  }
private:
  Foo& foo_;
};

class Demo : public ::testing::Test
{
  virtual void SetUp()
  {
    ::testing::InSequence dummy;
    EXPECT_CALL(foo_, bar(1)).Times(1);
    EXPECT_CALL(foo_, bar(2)).Times(::testing::AtMost(1)).
      WillOnce(::testing::InvokeWithoutArgs(ExpectCall1(foo_)));
  }
protected:
  Foo foo_;
};

TEST_F(Demo, Success1)
{
  foo_.bar(1);
}

TEST_F(Demo, Success2)
{
  foo_.bar(1);
  foo_.bar(2);
  foo_.bar(1);
}

TEST_F(Demo, Fail1)
{
  foo_.bar(1);
  foo_.bar(1);
}

TEST_F(Demo, Fail2)
{
  foo_.bar(1);
  foo_.bar(2);
}

TEST_F(Demo, Fail3)
{
  foo_.bar(1);
  foo_.bar(1);
  foo_.bar(2);
}
```